# I want to open the file in folder by using fopen()

Tags: c

```
for (j = 0; j < 900; j++)
{
    fptext = fopen("..\\n_file_list[j]", "w");


    fseek(fptext, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fptext);

    buffer_text = malloc(size + 1);
    memset(buffer_text, 0, size + 1);

    fseek(fptext, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fread(buffer_text, size, 1, fptext);
}
```

n_file_list has 900 txt file name.

I want to open these files but I can't.

I know how to open the file in the folder.

But I don't know how when the file name is in the array.

How can I open it??

Comment: Save ***n_file_list[j]*** in a string, fopen using the string.

Comment: You should close files after you finished working with them. The system may have limit of number of opened files.

Comment: `char buffer[1024000]; snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "..\\%s", n_file_list[j]); fptext = fopen(buffer, "w");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made a mistake here :

```
fptext = fopen("..\\n_file_list[j]", "w");
```

This line should be :

```
fptext = fopen(n_file_list[j], "w");
```